# How to update data in a database table using the data in a checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, checkboxlist

There are **2 tables known as master and kpi** in the databse.
**Columns in the master** table are,

> no, name, startdt, enddt, status

**Columns in kpi** table are,

> no, kpi_det

***Note: "no" in kpi table refers from "no" in master table.***
There can be more than one value for the kpi_det for the same "no"(several rows).
I have created an update query and gives me the following exception.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_COMPETITION_KPI'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.COMPETITION_KPI'. The duplicate key value is (3, OTHER).

What I expect to do is, update the values in kpi table and if there are more or less data in the checkboxlist than the number of data in the table, all of them should be added to the table or removed from the table respectively.   Any suggestions to make this work?

This is my query

```
public DataSet updateKPI(int compNo, string kpi)
{
    string strQuery = @"update [COMPETITION_KPI] set COMPETITION_KPI='" + kpi + "' " + Environment.NewLine +
                        @"where COMPETITION_NO='" + compNo + "' ";

    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnString, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
}
```

This is my c# code,

```
foreach (ListItem item in chkEditList.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        kpi = item.ToString();
        ds = db.updateKPI(compNo, kpi);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really need to refer that column? as i see you dont use **oop** when you do update operation in `updateKPI`. what happens if you remove the relation between them?

Comment: from the primary key violation error, it seems like you have made the "no" column in "kpi" table as a primary key. is it so. If it is referring to "no" column in "master" table, the it should be set as a foreign key.

Comment: Ofcourse its essential. Also dont worry about the relationship. It wont be changed

Comment: @mathewtinuthomas relationship is working properly for insert. This happens only during update